# How to load an external JavaScript script to (pure) SVG document?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have fairly large script within an .svg file and I'd like to get it out of the CDATA section into an external file. How to achieve this?

The HTML regular does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Track_animation.js" />
```

The documentation I have been able to find only concerns with JS embedded within the SVG itself. Is use of external scripts even possible?

Using OS X and Safari 4.0.4 for rendering.

Comment: **This** is regular HTML: `<script type="text/javascript" src="Track_animation.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this

```
<script xlink:href="file_name" />
```

Comment: `<script href="file_name" />` works better for me.

Answer (score 19):

Maybe you will need to have
`xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`
as attribute in your `<svg ... >`.

Comment: Required on Firefox 44.

Comment: Required on IE 11 as well

Comment: needed in chrome 65 aswell.

Comment: Also on Chromium 80.0.3987.162

Answer (score 4):

Seems [`xlink:href`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGMobile12/script.html#ScriptElementHrefAttribute) works (keeping the entry here, since it might help others):

```
<script xlink:href="Track_animation.js" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`<script type="text/javascript" xlink:href="svgEditarVisualizacao.js" xlink:actuate="onLoad" xlink:show="other" xlink:type="simple" />`